# Relativistic density

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, mass-energy, density

In the non-relativistic region of the space, with matter of mass $M$, and volume $V$ the density is given by

\begin{equation}
\rho=\frac{M}{V}
\end{equation}

If we encounter an equation, for example,
\begin{equation}
F=F(\rho,...)
\end{equation}
we simply substitute the first equation. However, if we want to consider relativity, then what is the density?

Comment: Some possibly related questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600196/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/608456/, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/674911/

Answer (score 6):

Matter density is the $00$ component of the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) $T^{\mu \nu}$. In order to find out what this component is in a different reference frame, simply perform a [Lorentz transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Tensor_formulation) on the two indices

$$T^{\mu \nu} \rightarrow T'^{\mu \nu}= \Lambda^{\mu}_{\,\,\alpha} \Lambda^{\nu}_{\,\,\beta} T^{\alpha \beta},$$

and pick out the $00$ component in the new (primed) frame.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to ask this same question, but let me propose what I suspect the answer to be :

Relativistic M = $mc^2 \gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the familiar $1 \over {\sqrt{1 - \beta}}$

or, fully expanded ${1} \over {\sqrt{ 1 - {{v^2} \over {c^2}}}}$

Relativistic x (of which V = $x^3$) = $1 \over \gamma$

Putting that together, then, I expect relativistic density (M/V) for a non-moving body to be ${mc^2 \gamma^4}\over{V }$

I was planning to post a question here to confirm that perspective. Is there anyone here who can confirm?

Comment: Did you want to say $\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$?

Comment: It should be $\gamma=1/\sqrt{1-\beta^2}$.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! I’ve updated the response.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is to start with the stress energy tensor in the resting frame and transform it to a moving frame. Then the $T^{tt}$ component of the stress energy tensor in the moving frame is the density (in natural units). The details depend on the specific stress energy tensor used:

For a fluid at rest with density $\rho$ and pressure $p$ we have: $$T^{\mu\nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \rho  & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & p & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & p & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & p \\
\end{array}
\right) $$ so $$T^{\mu'\nu'}={\Lambda^{\mu'}}_\mu {\Lambda^{\nu'}}_\nu T^{\mu\nu} = \left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \gamma ^2 \left(p v^2+\rho \right) & v \gamma ^2 (p+\rho ) & 0 & 0 \\
 v \gamma ^2 (p+\rho ) & \gamma ^2 \left(\rho  v^2+p\right) & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & p & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & p \\
\end{array}
\right) $$

Other stress energy tensors would need to be worked out similarly. Note that the density in the moving frame is not merely a function of the density in the rest frame, but also includes terms due to the other components of the stress energy tensor in the rest frame.

Comment: Thank you! What is "p" in this example?

Comment: @JamesMcLellan pressure