# Special theory of relativity (change of things w.r.t to frames))

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames

If there is a circle in one frame(inertial and stationary),then what will the circle look like from another moving frame

Comment: Also see [How does the area of moving circle change?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/600196/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the radius of the circle is parallel to the direction of propagation of the moving frame, the circle would look like an ellipse due to length contraction in that direction.