# Does the length of a raft change as the stream bed slides by underneath?

Tags: special-relativity, length

Consider a [raft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raft), of length (distance between its two ends, a.k.a. the distance between ["bow" and "stern" of the raft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timber_rafting#Timber_rafting_in_the_southeastern_United_States)) $L_0$.

Now, the [river bed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_bed) slides by quite close underneath the raft, along the raft axis, at uniform speed $v \gt 0$.

Any two elements of the river bed onto which the raft bow and stern are mapped by a simultaneity projection shall correspondingly have distance $L_{\text{proj}} = L_0 \, \sqrt{ 1 - \frac{ v^2 }{ c^2 } }$ from each other, of course.

Has the length of the raft therefore changed ?

---

Synopsis of comments (which recently have been "moved to chat", where, unfortunately, they may not be archived for long):

The assignment of a specific length value $L_0$ as "length of the raft" was criticized for *"being only true in the raft's rest frame."*

In response it has been noted that the relevant identifiable constituents of the raft are indeed supposed to be and to remain at rest wrt. each other, thus being members of the same one inertial frame, and only of this "own" one inertial frame. Therefore, any imaginable statements about "the raft not being in its rest frame" are counterfactual and to be rejected anyways; while the assignment of $L_0$ as "length of the raft (with the raft in its rest frame)" remains applicable.

Additionally it has been noted that $L_{\text{prej}}$, i.e. the distance between any two constituents of the river bed who are identified by one simultaneity projection of raft bow and stern to the constituents of the river bed, can be referred to as "length of the simultaneity projection of the raft to the river bed".

Comment: I have [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131191/discussion-on-question-by-user12262-does-the-length-of-a-raft-change-as-the-stre) a discussion that seemed to have concluded. Please don’t re-add parts of that discussion as comments; instead, edit them into the post.

Comment: This seems closely related to the question of [whether the pole fits in the barn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox).

Comment: I think @user12262 seems to be doing an excellent job of arguing at cross purposes. The OP posed the question about whether the length of the raft has changed, and has been answered. All the subsequent chat seems to be going in circles.

Answer (score 3):

When measured in the frame of the river bed, the raft appears foreshortened in its direction of motion.

The reason is that when considered simultaneously in the frame of the review bed, the two ends of the raft are being considered at different times in the rest frame of the raft, the bow being considered earlier than the stern- that means the position of the bow of the raft is considered first, and then the stern has time to move forward slightly before its position is considered, leading to the length being reduced.

The effect is entirely reciprocal. Suppose people on the raft drop simultaneous markers from each end onto the river bed. In the frame of the bed, the marker at the stern of the raft is dropped first, thus allowing the bow of the raft to move further along before its marker is dropped- the result is that the distance between the two markers in the frame of the bed is greater than the apparent distance between the markers in the frame of the raft (ie it appears to have been foreshortened from the raft's perspective).

Addendum

The raft does not shrink as a consequence of moving, although its length is shorter when measured in a reference frame moving with respect to the raft. If you believe the raft actually shrinks in an absolute sense, then you are quite wrong. The raft is at rest in its own frame. If its length is measured in n different frames at once, each moving at a different speed with respect to the raft, then the raft would have to 'shrink' to n different lengths at the same time, which is clearly nonsense.

Addendum 2

It is not necessary to cite material objects such as rafts and river beds- SR is ultimately a description of space and time in an abstract sense. If you have two points a fixed distance apart in one inertial frame, then the distance between them at any one time in that frame is greater than the distance between them at any one time in any other frame moving with respect to them.

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"When measured in the frame of the river bed, the raft appears foreshortened in its direction of motion."_ -- (Whatever that's supposed to mean ... Surely you don't mean to suggest that gravel stones below water should be mistaken for bow and stern of a raft; or that formula in the OP is wrong ? ...) Anyways, referring to my explicit OP question: Has the length of the raft therefore changed ? (yes, or no, or what else?). [continued]

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"The effect is entirely reciprocal. Suppose people on the raft drop simultaneous markers from each end onto the river bed. [...]_" -- To analyze this statement the notation ought to be explicit enough to express the "direction" of the applied simultaneity projection, e.g.

$$L_{(\text{proj}\rightarrow \text{bed})} [ \, \text{bow}, \text{stern} \, ] = L_0 \, \sqrt{ 1 - (v/c)^2}$$

and

$$L_{(\text{proj}\rightarrow \text{raft})} [ \, \text{marker B}, \text{marker S} \, ] = L_0 = L[ \, \text{marker B}, \text{marker S} \, ] \, \sqrt{ 1 - (v/c)^2},$$ where [contd.]

Comment: ... where $L_0$ denotes the length of the raft (as above, of course), and $L[ \, \text{marker B}, \text{marker S} \, ]$ denotes the distances between the markers as they rest in the river bed; and where, of course, the speed of the raft constituents wrt. the (inertial frame of the) river bed constituents and the speed of the river bed constituents wrt. the (inertial frame of the) raft constituents is equally: $v$.

Comment: See my addendum to my answer

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"Addendum"_ _"The raft does not shrink as a consequence of moving,"_ -- Nor, indeed, as a consequence of anybody else moving ("along"; e.g. the (constituents of the) river bed). Much better already! +1. _"although its length is shorter when measured in a reference frame moving wrt. the raft."_ -- Wrong! -1. (The length of any projection of the raft into the river bed system, i.e. $L_{\text{proj}}$ in the OP, or with more expressive notation: $L_{(\text{proj}\rightarrow \text{bed})} [ \, \text{bow}, \text{stern} \, ]$, **is not the length of the raft** which ought to be measured).

Comment: Marco Ocram: "_Addendum 2_" "_It is not necessary to cite material objects [...]_" -- Yes: "Raft and river bed" of the OP are just convenient stand-ins for more abstract, generic systems of "material points", in relation to each other. But I do insist on "Einstein's principal proclamation": ["_All our space-time verifications invariably amount to a determination of space-time coincidences {... such as ...}  meetings of two or more {...} material points._"](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/165?highlightText=coincidences). Even you're referring to _"points"_ (instead events):

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"If you have two points a fixed distance apart in one inertial frame, then [it] is greater than the distance between them at any one time in any other [IF ...]."_ -- No: "If you have two material points a fixed distance apart in one inertial frame, then it is greater than the distance between any two material points of another inertial frame which are identified by simultaneous projection of the two former points." Or for short, especially regarding Einstein's unfortunate formulation of 1905: "The length of a stick is larger than the length **of the projection** of the stick."

Comment: I think my definition is less ambiguous than yours- when you say 'simultaneous' projection, in which of the two frames do you mean the condition of simultaneity applies?

Comment: Marco Ocram: _"[...] when you say 'simultaneous' projection"_ -- My mistake, sorry! The correct technical term is, of course, "simultaneity projection"; cmp. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/675393/12262 & ref.s therein. _"in which of the two frames do you mean the condition of simultaneity applies?"_ In the inertial frame **into which** the projection (or the mapping) is made; the "range". And the OP equation is of course derived with this assignment. _"[...] my definition"_ -- ... talks about the raft "[being] in a frame in which, factually, it is not". That's called "counterfactual".

Answer (score -1):

The raft does not change its length; neither in consequence of the river bed moving wrt. to the raft, nor in consequence of the raft thereby moving wrt. the river bed (nor in consequence to any other system moving wrt. the raft).

The length value $L_{\text{proj}}$ is a value of distance between certain pairs of constituents of the river bed; namely of pairs which are, pair by pair, identified by simultaneity projection of the raft bow and of raft stern to the (inertial system of the) river bed. Therefore $L_{\text{proj}}$ is, by construction, not the length of the raft, its value is different from the value of the length of the raft, $L_0$, and $L_{\text{proj}}$ should accordingly not be called "length of the raft".

Instead, the length value $L_{\text{proj}}$ is, and can accordingly be called, the "length of the simultaneity projection of the raft into the (inertial system of the) river bed"; or in the given context for short: "the length of the projection of the raft".

Comment: You are using stack exchange to promote a personal preference for a peculiar terminology. I wouldn't mind that, but your proposal seems to add no value while losing brevity. What is wrong with using proper length and length instead of your proposed length and length of the simultaneity projection?